# Exchange Management Shell doesn't connect to closest Exchange server

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-server, remote-server

So I have a management server that has just the tools installed on it. Another note to add is that the EMS is actually being published as a remote app. When I open the command prompt, it pops up with an error saying that "there are no Exchange Servers in the site [AD site]" and then proceeds to connect to a server that is not the closest one.

I have tried changing the site link cost between the management server site and the closest Exchange server site to a lower cost than the site that contains the Exchange server that the management server connects to, but to no avail.

What else am I missing?

Also, I've checked the firewall, and there aren't any issues there. When it connects to the non-closest server, I can type `Connect-ExchangeServer [fqdn of the closest exchange server]` and it connects with no problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Manu How do I make cmdlets appear like your suggested change?

Comment: I just use the [formatting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) provided by StackOverflow and those who are available above the textbox when you ask or answer a question.

Comment: Ah, the `backtick`. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

I had that kind of issue a couple of time, here are my solutions which solved that issue for me (I think nr5 might be your solution):

1. Delete the windows profile and let the system create a new one.
2. Make sure a local Fireall isn´t causing any block here (e.g. Check also the local OS firewall)
3. Clearing the MMC Cache (File/Options --> Delete Files) or delete the file "Exchange Management Console.msc" from C:\Users\USERID\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\MMC\
4. Make sure the time is correct on the OS. If this isn´t the case a Kerberos authentication might not work correctly with some servers so the system try multiple.
5. To remove the previously cached server you can Delete the key NodeStructureSetting inside HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ExchangeServer\v14\AdminTools (more info's [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/whats_on_scotts_mind_today/2012/12/07/exchange-2010-unable-to-open-exchange-management-console-initialization-failed/))

Comment: I will give it a shot and let you know how it turns out. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Gosh man, no luck. It's being published as a remote app so that users don't even get profiles created locally on the management server.